# MYSQL SUM and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I want to have the name in the first colomn but i get an error. When i Let P.name out, the query works but I can't see the player name.

Right now I have the following query:

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Playernr, SUM (F.Amount)
FROM FINES F
INNER JOIN PLAYERS P
ON F.Playernr = P.Playernr
GROUP BY  P.Playernr
```

Thanks in advance for help

Onno

Comment: add the non-aggregated column in the `GROUP BY` clause. example, `GROUP BY P.Name, P.Playernr`

Comment: Your configuration must have the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) option enabled.

Comment: Just add the P.Name in the Group by, so the aggregate function can work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add it to the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Playernr, SUM (F.Amount)
FROM FINES F
INNER JOIN PLAYERS P
ON F.Playernr = P.Playernr
GROUP BY  P.Name,P.Playernr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(P.Name) as Name, P.Playernr, SUM (F.Amount)
FROM FINES F
INNER JOIN PLAYERS P
ON F.Playernr = P.Playernr
GROUP BY  P.Playernr
```

or add `P.Name` to the `Group BY`

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Playernr, SUM (F.Amount)
FROM FINES F
INNER JOIN PLAYERS P
ON F.Playernr = P.Playernr
GROUP BY  P.Name,P.Playernr
```

Answer (score 0):

When `GROUP BY` used, only group by column and aggregation function can be projected. Remove P.Name in projection column or add P.Name in GROUP BY

```
SELECT P.Name, P.Playernr, SUM (F.Amount)
FROM FINES F
INNER JOIN PLAYERS P
ON F.Playernr = P.Playernr
GROUP BY  P.Playernr, P.Name
```

In other RDBMS, your query produces error.

think about below data:

```
P.Playernr   P.Name
A         B
A         C
A         D
```

then, P.Name is not in GROUP BY, which value is produced in SELECT P.Playernr. so, you must use aggregation function or add P.Name in GROUP BY